# How to perform load testing of .net tcp binding WCF services(Any tools or approach)?

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp

We are working on one of the project and our requirement is to perform load/performance testing of wcf services hosted in windows where client uses .net tcp binding to communicate with the services.
We generally use Jmeter and Gatling for any load testing but as far as we know, these tools does not support TCP protocol services. We did some research and found some tools like like Visual studio 2010 ultimate edition which can be used for load testing of wcf services.
can anyone suggest anything/provide any assistance regarding the same e.g. tools, approach or  any references?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the simple steps from [here](http://www.sandeepsnotes.com/2013/05/load-and-performance-testing-of-wcf.html) for load and performance testing of WCF service.

[Here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) a quick how-to to implement WS testing using jmeter.

When the binding allows, you can start the service in the managed server and run NUnit tests against it.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73714/A-Better-Visual-Studio-2008-2010-Development-Serve

You can also choose [unit tests](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3308603-a1df-4680-bb26-e723300a3c16/wcf-web-performance-test)

And look into these 2 posts - they seem relate to your problem:

[WCF with tcp.net binding testing with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053754/wcf-with-tcp-net-binding-testing-with-jmeter)

[How to test a WCF Webservice with JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803974/how-to-test-a-wcf-webservice-with-jmeter)